# I made a software version of a semi-popular board game for free. Is that legal?

Tags: copyright, software, licensing, canada

All the code is 100% my own - I made it for practice, and to showcase my abilities to potential employers. To facilitate this, I want to release the code open source on GitHub.

I credit the game's designer in the opening menu, and use the title in my title. Surely since I'm not running adds on the site I plan to host it on, or monetize it in any way, I should't be in any legal trouble?

Thought I'd ask first. 
What kind of licence would I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the game is out of copyright, e.g. chess, snakes and ladders, Go, or checkers, your software would probably be considered a derivative work of the copyrighted game and an actionable infringement.

The fact that you do not monetize it is not a defense.

You would need written permission in the form of a license agreement from the copyright owner to do this legally. The penalties for violating copyright laws in this way could be punishingly serious.

Comment: How could games like chess or Go ever be copyrighted? If these games were invented today, would the description of the rules of the game, artwork (creative elements of the design of the board and the pieces, etc.) be copyrightable, or the actual rules themselves?

Comment: @Brandin It would be the former, but the question indicates that no effort whatsoever is made to change the game other than the software format and that the game's creators are expressly acknowledged.